# xamarin ios - bunde resources not found

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am developing ios and android app with xamarin. I have problem with loading images as bundled resource.

Everything worked for few months and now for no reasaon when I start app I get exception that image is null. It worked until now, casing is ok everything is ok. I use vs2013.

> public static UIImage logo = UIImage.FromBundle("logo");

But when I build app in xamarin studio on mac(instead vs2013 on windows) than everything is working fine :(

Can anybody give me a clue what it could be :(?

Comment: If I understand you correctly the very same solution compiles on both Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio (on Mac), but the VS version yields Null Exceptions? Could you check whether the resources are indeed marked as BundleResource? And could you also try removing the app from the device and then retesting. I've encountered some instances where the app would not deploy fully and wouldn't update all it's bundled resources as a result.

Comment: Yes, You understood well. I did it all - all resources are set as BundleResource, reinstalled app on simulator :(.

Comment: Any information in the Console or something? Afaik UIImage.FromBundle can return null only in two cases. The image doesn't exist, or the image isn't in a correct format.

You could temporarily try using UIImage.FromFile("Resources/logo") instead. Just to see whether it works...

Comment: I think something is wrong with deployment of resources, but I can't figure out what

Comment: First things coming to mind are problems translating filepaths in Windows and iOS. Differences are: / vs \ and Case-sensitivity. Additionally native iOS apps don't like subfolders for Resources, but in Xamarin this usually works.